# Spring Boot ECS service cannot connect to DocumentDB cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, aws-documentdb

In AWS I have a Spring Boot application running in ECS Fargate in a Docker container, which I deployed using CloudFormation. In the same VPC (with two subnets) I deployed a DocumentDB cluster with a single instance. When run locally with MongoDB (both in-memory and as a Docker image), the Spring Boot application connects fine (both in the IDE and using Docker Compose, respectively).

In CloudFormation I injected the DocumentDB instance as a Spring Boot environment parameter in the ECS container definition:

```yaml
- Name: SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_HOST
  Value: !GetAtt DbCluster.Endpoint
- Name: SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_PORT
  Value: !GetAtt DbCluster.Port
```

When I deploy the CloudFormation stack, in the console I can go to the DocumentDB cluster and see that it shows the database cluster host as something like this:

`foo-bar-xxxxxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com`

The password is stored in Secrets Manager and attached to the database; that secret shows the same host name.

I can go to a Cloud9 instance in the same VPC and connect to `foo-bar-xxxxxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com` using `mongosh`.

When my Spring Boot instance starts up, its logs show:

> `2023-04-11T23:18:39.610Z INFO 1 --- [ main] org.mongodb.driver.client : MongoClient with metadata {"driver": {"name": "mongo-java-driver|sync|spring-boot", "version": "4.8.2"}, "os": {"type": "Linux", "name": "Linux", "architecture": "amd64", "version": "5.10.173-154.642.amzn2.x86_64"}, "platform": "Java/Eclipse Adoptium/17.0.6+10"} created with settings MongoClientSettings{… clusterSettings={hosts=[foo-bar-xxxxxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017], srvServiceName=mongodb, mode=SINGLE, …`

Note that the database cluster host Spring Boot is using the same one I connected to from Cloud9.

But eventually the Spring Boot application times out:

> `org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=foo-bar-xxxxxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadTimeoutException: Timeout while receiving message}, caused by {java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out}}]`

I even restarted the ECS task thinking maybe the database hadn't been initialized yet, but with the same result.

In Cloud 9, an `nslookup foo-bar-xxxxxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com` resolves to an IP address within the VPC. The security group (`AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup`) associated with the ECS service has no egress defined, so it defaults to allowing all egress to anywhere on any port (which I just confirmed via the console).

**If Spring Boot, Document DB, and Cloud9 are all running in the same VPC, any idea why Cloud9 can connect just fine to `foo-bar-xxxxxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com`, but the Spring Boot ECS Fargate instance cannot? Where should I be looking?**

I should also mention I'm using [Service Connect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-connect.html), where I've set up a Cloud Map namespace `example.internal` and enabled Service Connect for the ECS service with the a port name of `my-service`. I understand that Service Connect sets up some sort of sidecar "proxy" container running alongside my task container. Could this Service Connect proxy somehow be blocking my service outgoing requests? Do I need to do something further to allow the service to make connections to the database cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is that the DocumentDB instance was configured to use SSL/TLS but that Spring Boot Data MongoDB apparently does not support SSL/TLS by default. (I am grateful to https://stackoverflow.com/a/66807514 which alerted me to this possibility.)

The best thing to do would be to enable SSL/TLS in Spring Boot, but I don't immediately know how to do that in a *fully automated way* in AWS using CloudFormation. (If you know how to do that please let me know, but I imagine I'll have to spend days researching it myself because the examples I've seen so far have loads of "manually do this and that" which is unacceptable.) So for the meantime here is how you can turn off SSL/TLS on your DocumentDB cluster using CloudFormation.

**Make sure you have no public ingress to your DocumentDB cluster if you go this route.** (No pun intended.) Better would be to put the Spring Boot app and the DocumentDB cluster in a private subnet. (Even better would be to enable SSL/TLS in your Spring Boot application of course.)

First you can't use the `default.docdb4.0` which is created automatically, because it has TLS enabled. Create a custom [`AWS::DocDB::DBClusterParameterGroup`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-docdb-dbclusterparametergroup.html):

```yaml
  DbClusterNoTls:
    Type: AWS::DocDB::DBClusterParameterGroup
    Properties: 
      Name: docdb-4.0-no-tls
      Family: docdb4.0
      Parameters:
        # whatever other parameters you want to set here
        tls: disabled
```

Then reference that in your [`AWS::DocDB::DBCluster`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-docdb-dbcluster.html):

```yaml
  DbCluster:
    Type: AWS::DocDB::DBCluster
    Properties: 
      DBClusterIdentifier: db-cluster
      EngineVersion: 4.0.0
      DBClusterParameterGroupName: !Ref DbClusterNoTls
      …
```

Comment: I have included this information in a tutorial on using Spring Boot with DocumentDB, which I just posted at [_Connecting Spring Boot to AWS DocumentDB with Secure Credentials_](https://www.garretwilson.com/blog/2023/04/24/spring-boot-documentdb-secure-credentials).